# Angular 8 Добавить событие (click) к динамически добавленному элементу

Tags: javascript, события, dom, angular, angular8

Есть изначально спрятанное всплывающее окно, и несколько кастомных элементов.
В зависимости от того на какой элемент кликнул пользователь всплывающее окно показывается с определённым наполнением

Всплывающее окно:

```
<div [class.hidden]="tooltipHidden" id="tooltip">
    <ul id="tooltip-content">

    </ul>
</div>
```

Один из кастомных элементов:

```
<div (click)="toggleTooltip(2)"></div>
```

Функция toggleTooltip():

```
toggleTooltip(id) {
    document.getElementById('tooltip-content').innerHTML = this.tooltipContent[id - 1];
    this.tooltipHidden = !this.tooltipHidden;
}
```

При этом `tooltipContent` это массив строк с html-разметкой (просто куча `<li>` элементов). Не самый лучший способ, но на нём уже работает большая часть сайта.

**НО!** Проблема в том, что при клике на один из кастомных элементов нужно вставить кнопку с функционалом angular. Пример:

```
<li (click)="openTest()>TEST</li>
```

А angular не обрабатывает динамически добавленные элементы.

Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Очень просто - не использовать `document.getElementById('tooltip-content').innerHTML = this.tooltipContent[id - 1]`. Сложный - компилировать html. Я предлагаю переделать на angular way.

Comment: Да, способ @StepanKasyanenko уместен, но я решил другим путём.
Навесил обработчик событий на родительский элемент (на сам `ul`) и при клике на него проверял попал ли клик на нужный элемент, и вызывал функцию с нужными параметрами.

Comment: Решение, конечно, рабочее. Но - костыльное. Лучше не создавать лишние проблемы и один раз хорошенько отрефакторить код.

Comment: @Aleksandr в чем проблема оставить `li click` в DOMе просто обернув в ngIf? Мне просто не совсем понятно, зачем хранить где-то массив строк с html-разметкой, это не то, чтобы костыль, а вообще похоже на стрельбу в ногу)